# A hyperlink on Crystal Reports should open another report and pick Session value

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, asp.net-2.0

I am using Visual Studio 2005 Professional Edition [ASP.NET with C#].

I have a Crystal Report with a column is shown as a hyperlink. On clicking any hyperlinked value of any row, another report should open but I have three issues to be addressed:

1. The URL of the second report should be handled via Server.Transfer method to hide the page name from the URL.
2. The hyperlinked text, where the user has clicked to open second report, should be passed to the second report.
3. The second report is connected with SQL command as database back-end. I want to pass a Session value as a parameter to the SQL command being used by the second report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're hyperlink will need to reference a URL that will perform a Server.Transfer--Crystal Reports does not support this.
2. You will need to embed this text in the query string.
3. You will need to embed the logon token in the query string.

To dynamically construct a querystring, edit the conditional formula that is associated with the field's Hyperlink infomation (right click field; Format Field...; Hyperlink tab).  It might resemble:

```
//change to reflect your situation
"http://server:port/resource/redirect.aspx?reportname=" + [report name here] + "&token=" + [logon token here]
```

If you are using BusinessObjects Enterprise, you may want to investigate [URLReporting](http://devlibrary.businessobjects.com/businessobjectsxir2/en/devsuite.htm#en/BOE_SDK/boesdk_java_dg_doc/doc/boesdk_java_dg/Report_Linking.html).